# Equation to generate Rolemaster combat tables results

Tags: combat, rolemaster, rolemaster-standard-system, rolemaster-fantasy-roleplaying

Rolemaster combat tables present very different results depending on armor type and weapon, but are those results generated by some type of **equation** or **algorithm**? Maybe a different equation/algorithm for each weapon? I doubt they were generated by hand.

EDIT: I'll add some more information. For example, in Arm's Law page 11, the attack table for the broadsword is as follows:

[image: RM broadsword attack table]

The damage seems to follow some type of mathematical progression, always more damage when you get closer to 150, and the critical strike is also more dangerous. Critical strike type seems to follow, in this example, K-P-S-K order at first. I don't know, I was wondering if I could reduce the table to a mathematical expression.

Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47092/discussion-on-question-by-joeperkins-equation-to-generate-rolemaster-combat-tabl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen any official statistics or formulas for the Rolemaster combat tables, if they did exist I'd be amazed if they gave them out as it would negate the need for Arms law. However the newer versions of Arms Law do streamline the process a little by grouping blocks of numbers.

In the classic Rolemaster Companion's there were several attempts to streamline the book system of RM to simplier single-page affairs.

**Rolemaster Companion III** (ICE #1700) presented a system where dice rolls were used and a modifier for armour was made; for example:

> Make a d% open ended roll; add and subtract OB and DB as usual. Rolled dice are then used to generate damage and multiplied for a high roll.

**Rolemaster Companion I** (ICE #1500) has more of what you're looking for, although it's a bit intimidating. The *Condensed Combat System* attempts to recreate the tables with a formula system.

Take a seat and here we go...

[image]

[image]

1. Roll the attack, check for fumble/failure, modify by OB/DB and other factors as usual. This is the **IAV**.
2. Cross-index the attacks Table Type (Arms Law = AL) with the targets armour type in the Armour DB mod area, subtract this from the IAV. Then add the Weapon OB mod for the armour type. This is the **FAN**.
3. If the **FAN** is greater than the *To Hit Threshold* the attack does damage. Criticals result if it has passed the appropriate threshold.
4. To determine how many hits occured divide (**FAN-THT**) by the *Basic Hit Factor* (The number in brackets on the attack statistics area)

> DAMAGE = ((OB-DB-ArmourMod+WeaponMod)-THT)/BHF

Let's try a worked example everyone!

Bob the Orc has a Falchion and an OB of 95, he attacks Eric the Thief who has a DB of 25 and is wearing chainmail (AT 13). Eric isn't parrying because he's been distracted by a malevolent moose.
Bob rolls a 50 to attack and the GM gets out his slide rule.

The Falchion has an OB mod of +4 vs chain and a BHF of 4.4.
AT 13 has a DB modifier of 15.
The THT for chain is 26.

So Bob's FAN is 95 (OB) +50 (Roll)-25 (DB) -15 (ArmourMod) +4 (Weapon Mod) = 109
The THT for chain is 26, so the final result is 83.

So Bob does (83/4.4) hits = 18.8 = 18 hits and a C critical (C threshold is 100 for "Ch" in the threshold table)

Easy, right?

Comparing this to Arms Law for Bobs attack value of 95+50-25 = 120 = 17 C Slash 
Not a bad approximation for this highly scientific comparison!

The full table I'm not going to print as that's taking copyright too far, but you can pick up a copy of RMC I for about £15, it's also on drivethru RPG for $15.

Comment: I got the RMC I, but I didn't read it all. That seems exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

[Rolemaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolemaster) was first published in 1980. For all you millennials out there, 1980 was near the end of the "dark ages" when computers were the size of cars and kept in specially air conditioned rooms and attended by a strange priesthood of computer scientists who performed elaborate rituals to keep them operating. There were desktop computers but these were still essentially toys still awaiting the "killer app" (which, by the way, was VisiCalc the first spreadsheet).

While you cannot prove a negative: **it is more likely than not that these were generated by hand according to the algorithm in the designer's head**.

That said, you could certainly derive a mathematical equation for the table. It is *extremely* unlikely that this equation will be simple. It will almost certainly look like the equations of a geocentric astronomer trying to deny the sun is at the centre of the solar system.

Build a lookup table - it will be easier.

Comment: 1979 was the middle of the age of microcomputers (desk-sized; where “micro” was relative to mainframes) and we already had the first Apple Macintosh and the killer home app of the Basic programming language. So the history of computing is a bit off, but the general point stands: computers were rare and expensive and paper & pencil and eccentric designers is more likely.

Comment: The Rolemaster Combat Minion application has automated combat lookup tables: http://ironcrown.com/blog/2014/02/04/rolemaster-combat-minion-out-now/.

Comment: I think they generated the data with some algorithm and then added some little manual changes, maybe. An reasonable approximation would be enough, though. Pretty interesting RobertF's link, I didn't remember they offer that software.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The first Mac was released in 1984, but by 1979 you did have the Apple II (released in 1977) and early 1980 you had the Apple III, the VIC-20, and the ZX80 being released.

Comment: I first encounter Macs at the University of Sydney in 1986 and we that was the first year they had them. We used them in first year before moving to "traditional" Vax microcomputers.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - the Macintosh wasn't released until 1984, see the famed Orwellian commercial. The Apple available in 1980 was the ][+.

Comment: Yes, sorry, right year, wrong computer: by 1979 Apple had the Apple I and II to compete against all the other machines available in the “hobby” era of home computing (TRS-80, Commodore, etc.). Basic was already a “killer app” before VisiCalc. (VisiCalc was just the first “killer app” from the perspective of business users, and therefore the first runaway commercial success in software, but not the first entirely.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking for an xls version of the combat tables I found a revised version from [The Guild Companion's issue of May 2002](http://www.guildcompanion.com/scrolls/2002/may/revisedweapontables.html):

> The goal was to find a solution for two well-known "armour anomalies",
>   the relative ineffectiveness of lighter armour types and the "double
>   penalty" (early concussion damage plus Quickness penalties) associated
>   with heavier armour types.

For example, the new much reduced broadsword table would be:

[image: Broadsword revised combat table]

> The tables operate in much the same way as the regular weapon attack
>   tables. The armour types are listed in columns and the results are
>   derived from the standard OB - DB calculation. However, instead of
>   giving an entry at each individual number up to 150, only intervals of
>   when concussion damage and criticals occur are given. Each number
>   listed within the tables along the critical severity type (A-E) rows
>   indicates the minimum number needed to achieve that critical severity.
>   Concussion damage is calculated by subtracting 75 from the final
>   result of the OB – DB calculation and then dividing this result by the
>   divisional factor 'Div'. The calculation of concussion damage can also
>   be tabulated by referring to the Concussion Damage Calculation Table.

And an example of use:

> Looking up the result of 112 on the revised Broadsword table against
>   armour type 1 would yield the following.
>
> Concussion Damage:            (Result - 75) / 'Div'
>
> [The division factor 'Div' can be found on the table for each AT]
>
> (112 - 75) / '3' = 12.33 (round up to 13)
>
> Critical Severity: 112 is more than 100 which gives a 'D' critical but
>   less than 120 which gives an 'E' critical. The result of 112 falls
>   within the 'D' critical range.
>
> Critical Type:                (Critical Type 1/Critical Type 2)
>
> [Can be found along the same row as 'Crit' for each amour type]
>
> In this case the critical types are S/P (slash/puncture). Odd numbers
>   indicate the first critical type (slashes), while even numbers
>   indicate the second (punctures). 112 is an even number, so a puncture
>   is the critical type.
>
> Final result:                   13DP

It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a very good approximation :).